# The only connected subsets of $\mathbf{Q}$ are the singletons.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to understand and to figuring out how to prove this. Any hints that you could give me? I was thinking of starting with a subset with two elements and prove that it is disconnected. But I don't know if that's the correct approach.

Comment: Maybe, break the problem down: first prove that singletons are connected. Then prove every other set is not connected.

Comment: In the real numbers, every two-point set is disconnected, but $\Bbb R$ is connected. The key to that is that over $\Bbb R$ we have the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You'll use the fact that, between any two rational numbers, there's an irrational number.